# Why are some attributes not found in intellisense?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html

I can't see certain HTML attributes such as `tabindex` or `onblur` for standard divs in intellisense - and when writing them at design time they're underlined. However - they work fine when debugging.

Why is this?

Comment: try to download from here and try again http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js

Comment: You're talking about **HTML attributes**, not Javascript properties.

Comment: You should be able to see all [global attributes](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Attributes/_Global) in HTML intellisense.  Check that you are not in XHTML strict, which I don't believe offers the JavaScript events.  Although, I'm not sure any offer it because I haven't tried.

Comment: Standard divs also don't have `tabindex` and `onblur` attributes in HTML 4.01, but I'm not sure about HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually two possible reasons why intellisense doesn't pick them up:

1. The attributes were not mapped to properties in the control
2. The control is suppressing the attributes/properties

However, even though intellisense doesn't pick the attributes up, they still get added to the `Attributes` collection of the control and rendered to the page. It works because they're common attributes for all HTML elements, which is what the controls resolve to when rendered to the page.